# Woocommerce Category Specific Button on product page

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

I the code below to show a button on the single product page:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','cmk_additional_button');
function cmk_additional_button() {
    echo '<button type=”submit” class=”button alt”>test</button>';
}
```

This is working right and show this additional button on all products.

Now, how can I restrict this so it only shows on single product pages that are within certain categories, for example "Commercial Gym Equipment" only?

Thanks.

Comment: Have tried something yet? May be my answer will put you on the right track…

Answer (score 0):

You can do it adding some conditionals to your code like below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'cmk_additional_button' );
function cmk_additional_button() {
    global $product;

    // Set HERE your product categories (IDs, slugs or Names)
    $category = array( "Commercial Gym Equipment" );

    // Displaying button for single product pages and your defined product category
    if( is_product() && has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . __( "test", "woocommerce" ) . '</button>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works for WooCommerce 3.0+